# Unable to pass --prod --aot flags to ng build

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm unable to pass flags to ng build.

I have next line:
"build:aot:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8092 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --prod"

it runs only ng build without flags. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you try `node --max_old_space_size=8092 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot=true --prod=true`

Comment: Tried without luck (

Comment: You don't need to provide both flags - passing `-prod` turns on AOT.

Comment: Yes, but no matter how many parameters you pass. Just -prod didn't work too.

Comment: Can we use this AOT mode for dev or qa mode by passing --aot flags in ng build command like "ng build  --env=dev --aot".                                                  Actually I have tried but its not compiling with 'AOT'? Could any one suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the position of flags. Change `ng build --aot --prod` to `ng build --prod --aot`. Same issue exists on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2418).

Here is your complete line:

```
"build:aot:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8092 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot"
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating packages to latest version and npm itself - works as desired.